# Vue CLI Service production build without version code?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I have a vue project and I use `vue-cli-service build` to build the project for production.

I noticed by default when I build the files, the resource name are having some kind of version code like

```
app.34fc5700.js
chunk-vendors.c7da5824.js
```

Is there a way to get rid of it?

I'm using `vue.config.js`, there's no `webpack.conf.js` in my project, and this is how it looks like:

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_ROOT_PATH,
    outputDir: process.env.VUE_APP_BUILD_DIR,
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.resolve.symlinks(false);
        config.plugin('html').init((Plugin, args) => {
            const newArgs = {
                ...args[0],
            };
            newArgs.minify && (newArgs.minify.removeAttributeQuotes = false);
            return new Plugin(newArgs);
        });
    },
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                additionalData: '@import "@/scss/_variables.scss";',
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the option [`filenamehashing`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing) is something you need. Basically this option is enabled by default so you might need to turn it off:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  filenameHashing: false,
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Didn't know there's a config for that, thank you!

Comment: BTW sounds like we have the same name :) Glad to hear that helps

Comment: Lol not surprised, there will be at least 7 people turning their heads around if you call this name on the street.